# What is Log Mechanism in AWS cloud watch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have recently started learning about AWS cloud watch and I want to understand the concept of creating Logs so I went through a lot of links like
https://aws.amazon.com/answers/logging/centralized-logging/
I could understand that we can create log groups but and logs are basically to track activity. Is there anything more to it. When do the logs get created. 
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get more details about Log Groups and CloudWatch Logs Concepts [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CloudWatchLogsConcepts.html)

Following is the extract from that page

> **Log Events**
>
> A log event is a record of some activity recorded by the application or resource being monitored. The log event record that
>   CloudWatch Logs understands contains two properties: the timestamp of
>   when the event occurred, and the raw event message. Event messages
>   must be UTF-8 encoded.
>
> **Log Streams**
>
> A log stream is a sequence of log events that share the same source. More specifically, a log stream is generally intended to
>   represent the sequence of events coming from the application instance
>   or resource being monitored. For example, a log stream may be
>   associated with an Apache access log on a specific host. When you no
>   longer need a log stream, you can delete it using the aws logs
>   delete-log-stream command. In addition, AWS may delete empty log
>   streams that are over 2 months old.
>
> **Log Groups**
>
> Log groups define groups of log streams that share the same retention, monitoring, and access control settings. Each log stream
>   has to belong to one log group. For example, if you have a separate
>   log stream for the Apache access logs from each host, you could group
>   those log streams into a single log group called
>   MyWebsite.com/Apache/access_log.

And to answer your question "*When do the logs get created.*", basically that is completely dependent on your application. However, whenever they are created they get streamed to cloudwatch streams (if you have installed the cloudwatch agent and are streaming that particular log)

The advantage of using cloudwatch is that you can retain logs even after your EC2 instance is terminated and you dont need to SSH into the resource to check the logs, you can simply get that from AWS Console